# PHP str_replace Difficulty with Double Quotes

Tags: php, quotes, str-replace

I am trying to clean up text that a user could input in a form.  I would appreciate any faster methods and extra precautions I could take to make sure that bad code is not injected via this form.  ButI am having particular trouble with removing double quotes.

My code is:

```
str_replace(array('<','>',')','\$','(', '?', '.', ',' ,'!', '-', '+', '/', '\*', '\\', '"'), " ", $text)
```

But it will not match and remove the slanted quotes, like from MS word, “ to " which is the normal double quotes.

Can you help me with fixing this?

*I am using POST for the form and I am not using the input for anything more than parsing it.

Thanks

This is all that I am trying to do

```
str_replace(array('"'), " ", $text)
```

Replace double quotes with a space, but PHP is not recognizing double quotes from a program like Microsoft Word.  Thanks

Comment: What do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: I am just trying to remove the slanted quotes from text but it will only recognize the straight double quotes

Comment: Sorry it does not work adding “ to the array

Comment: @ChasingDeath 's solution works for me... `echo str_replace('“','',"asdasdasdasdas“");`

Comment: You should also want to try "&quot;". This one also saves me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MS smart quotes can be removed with this function.

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

Or add them to your code:

```
str_replace(array('<','>',')','\$','(', '?', '.', ',' ,'!', '-', '+', '/', '\*', '\\', '"', chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148)), " ", $text)
```

http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php

Comment: I used this code but the characters weren't stripped. Why would my PHP code not find an strip these characters?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

There is [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function that protects all unknown output from breaking HTML.

Comment: I am just trying to remove the slanted quotes from text but it will only recognize the straight double quotes

Comment: Slanted quotes are a different character than straight double quotes. Just make sure to write slanted quotes into your replace function in that case (and make sure the file itself is in UTF-8 encoding (where you have the slanted quotes replacement) if the data is in UTF-8.

Comment: Do you happen to know what that character entry is?  I cannot simply copy and paste it in.

Comment: Google for it. You can just copy paste from any web document, like from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Answer (score 1):

You could whitelist characters instead of blacklisting some only. Then replace any character that is not whitelisted with the space and afterwards normalize multiple spaces into one space.

```
$filtered = preg_replace(array('~\W~', '~[ ]{2, }~'), ' ', $text);
```